# Flex/Actionscript Function to Calculate Random Point IN Circle

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here so I was looking to see if anyone had any thoughts or suggestions.
I'm trying to create a function that returns a random point WITHIN a circle.
The following code gives me random points along the edge of the circle.
Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks!

```
private function getPointInCircle(tmpRadius:int):Point {
    var x:int;
    var y:int;

    var a:Number = Math.random() * 360;
    x = radius * Math.cos(a * (Math.PI / 180));
    y = radius * Math.sin(a * (Math.PI / 180));

    trace("x: " + x + "y: " + y);
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two degrees of freedom, one is the angle, which you had, and the other is the distance from the center:

```
var d:Number = Math.random()*radius
var a:Number = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
x = d*Math.cos(a);
y = d*Math.sin(a);
```

If you have your circle centered in `(x0,y0)` and not in `(0,0)` you modify like this:

```
x = x0 + d*Math.cos(a);
y = y0 + d*Math.sin(a);
```

*Trivia: The [circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle) is just the border line. If you want to refer to the area delimited by the border, you say [disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_%28mathematics%29).*

Comment: Thanks so much Alin.  Yes, I completely forgot to make the distance random - hence why the points were all equal to the radius.  Thanks - it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try a random angle and random radius in a circular coordinate system, then convert to cartesian. Also, did you notice that your parameter is `tmpRadius` and in your function you are using `radius`?

```as
var a = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
var r = Math.random() * radius;
var x = r * Math.cos(a);
var y = r * Math.sin(a);
```

Comment: yes, the tmpRadius is not being used as of yet. Thanks for catching that and for providing an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do provide a sort of random point inside a circle, but they are not uniformly distributed.  Regions near the center will have a higher concentration of points per unit area than regions near the rim.

To get a uniform distribution, you can either:

(a) Find a random point in the axis square around the circle.

```
x = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * radius;
y = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * radius;
```

Test whether it's actually in the circle (`x * x + y * y <= r * r`).  Repeat until you find a valid point.

(b) Do a little math transformation to get appropriately distributed distance and angle.

```
uniform_random = P(dist < r) = (pi r^2) / (pi radius^2) = r^2 / radius^2

r = radius * sqrt(uniform_random)

var r = radius * sqrt(Math.random());
var theta = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
var x = r * Math.cos(theta);
var y = r * Math.sin(theta);
```